# Dot operation with cell value in Excel

Tags: excel

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Date | Filename |
| 2 | 1/1/2000 | Cat |
| 3 | 1/2/2000 | Dog |
| 4 | 1/3/2000 | Frog |

Here is a example of my excel file.

I have created a formula for getting my desire value.

`=VLOOKUP(A2, B2.csv!$A$2:$G$5388, 1, FALSE)`

I have cat.csv, dog.csv and frog.csv file in my folder, but how could I use the dot operation with the cell value in order to complete the formula. Since, if I just type the cell position with the dot csv, it doesn't work.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(A2, INDIRECT("'" & B2 & ".csv]sheet1'!$A$2:$G$5388"), 1, FALSE)

Comment: #REF! is generated.

Comment: can you please share your sample cat or dog.csv

Comment: When you say you get a ref error, is it due to the vlookup part or the indirect part? Test each bit separately. Also is the information on sheet 1?

Comment: If ref_text refers to another workbook (an external reference), the other workbook must be open. If the source workbook is not open, INDIRECT returns the #REF! error value - [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)